# aws free tier: EBS 30G and 2 million IOs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
30 GB of Amazon EBS Standard volume storage plus 2 million IOs and 1 GB snapshot storage
```

I know system(OS) partition is EBS too . My question is:

1. how do I know how many IOs I used?
2. system(OS) partition is included in 2 million ?  included in 30GB storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should be able to see than in:
Billing & Cost Management-> Bill Details

Under the Elastic Compute Cloud section.

2) Yes for both.